# Upload css and html saved in a folder to host server

Tags: html, css, file-upload

I'm new to programming generally. I have typed my css and html codes and saved in a folder. How do i upload this site to a host server. Thanks

Comment: Have you signed up for any hosting service?

Comment: FTP Software are for that purpose if you already have a hosting space. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is one among them

Comment: what is your purpose testing your website or deploying ?

Comment: Well plenty of answers here, feel free to tick the one you like best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome.
To upload the files to your hosted server, you would need to use a FTP program ( File Transfer Protocol). A good free one to use would be filezilla, which a quick google search will come up for you.

Once you have downloaded filezilla you will need your server FTP settings, which you can find on your Hosted servers control panel. (They generally get you to create a username and password) you would need the FTP setting and Port with your login details, to be able to log in and start uploading your files.

One thing to be careful of, is the URL links for images/pages etc, as they may be different than if they were on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP (file transfer protocol) to achieve this. Download a free FTP client such as FileZilla, input your hostname and login information, and then you simply navigate to your desired server location and drag and drop.

You can read more about FTP here
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I like the link, If he is new to uploading, that link sure is going to fry his head

Comment: @Ricky true, it was more intended to help explain what's going on behind the scenes then actually explain the process but you're right.

Comment: It made me laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually we have FTP (file transfer protocol) to send data to the server.

Softwares like Filezilla, for example, can connect and handle server's directories and files the way you want.

Anyway, you need to check the available   services with your hosting service.